# There is no indicator in custom tabhost

Tags: android

I want to create a custom tabhost, which contains an icon also. For the purpose I need to use a method. This method works fine, but the tab indicator is disappeared from the tab.

The code for the tab indicator is:

```
private View getTabIndicator(Context context, String title, int icon) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageResource(icon);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(title);
        return view;
    }
```

Main Activity is :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        Setting up a toolbar for the navigation purpose.

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        toolbar.setTitle(" Call History Control");
        toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//        The fragments management is done here

//        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
//        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
//
//        mTabHost.addTab(
//                mTabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator(" HOME"),
//                Home.class, null);
//        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("settings").setIndicator(" SETTINGS"),
//                Settings.class, null);
//
//        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("about").setIndicator(" ABOUT"),
//                About.class, null);


        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(getApplicationContext(),"HOME",R.drawable.ic_home)),
                Home.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("settings").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(getApplicationContext(),"SETTINGS",R.drawable.ic_settings)),
                Settings.class, null);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("about").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(getApplicationContext(),"ABOUT",R.drawable.ic_account)),
                About.class, null);

    }
```

The screeen shot is:
[image]